# Прижать кнопку к низу с правой стороны блока

Tags: css, css3

Как прижать кнопку, чтобы она была постоянно в низу, независимо от того сколько текста в блоке ?

```css
.array_blog {
  background: #FFF;
  margin-top: 8px;
  height: 220px;
  width: 600px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FDC04B;
  box-shadow: 0px 16px 19px -22px #000000;
}
.post-header {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #FED387;
  border-top: 1px solid #FDC04B;
}
.names_index {
  padding: 6px 15px;
  color: #F56C0F;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica;
  text-align: center;
}
.text {
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #555;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.leftimg {
  float: left;
  /* Выравнивание по левому краю */
  margin: 0px 15px 7px 8px;
  /* Отступы вокруг картинки */
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 6px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
.array_Button {
  float: right;
  margin: 20px 15px 0 0;
}
.myButton {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #fff6af;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #fff6af;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #fff6af;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffec64), color-stop(1, #ffab23));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffec64', endColorstr='#ffab23', GradientType=0);
  background-color: #ffec64;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #ffaa22;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #333333;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #ffee66;
}
.myButton:hover {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffab23), color-stop(1, #ffec64));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffab23', endColorstr='#ffec64', GradientType=0);
  background-color: #ffab23;
}
```

```html
<div class="array_blog">
  <div class="post-header">
    <div class="names_index">Заголовок статьи</div>
  </div>

  <div class="none_foto">
    <img alt="Foto" src="http://shots.ikbis.com/image/35515/large/Hummer_H2_89_1280x1024.jpg" width="200" height="150" class="leftimg" />
  </div>

  <div class="text">
    Текст текст текст текст
  </div>


  <div class="array_Button">
    <a href="">
      <div class="myButton">Читать далее ...</div>
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немножко исправил твой код css в `.array_blog` вставил `position: relative;` , а в `.array_Button` вставил  `position: absolute; bottom:0; right:0;`

```css
.array_blog {
  position: relative;
  background: #FFF;
  margin-top: 8px;
  height: 220px;
  width: 600px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FDC04B;
  box-shadow: 0px 16px 19px -22px #000000;
}
.post-header {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #FED387;
  border-top: 1px solid #FDC04B;
}
.names_index {
  padding: 6px 15px;
  color: #F56C0F;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica;
  text-align: center;
}
.text {
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #555;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.leftimg {
  float: left;
  /* Выравнивание по левому краю */
  margin: 0px 15px 7px 8px;
  /* Отступы вокруг картинки */
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 6px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
.array_Button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 8px 8px 0;
}
.myButton {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #fff6af;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #fff6af;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #fff6af;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffec64), color-stop(1, #ffab23));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffec64', endColorstr='#ffab23', GradientType=0);
  background-color: #ffec64;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #ffaa22;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #333333;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #ffee66;
}
.myButton:hover {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffab23), color-stop(1, #ffec64));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffab23', endColorstr='#ffec64', GradientType=0);
  background-color: #ffab23;
}
```

```html
<div class="array_blog">
  <div class="post-header">
    <div class="names_index">Заголовок статьи</div>
  </div>

  <div class="none_foto">
    <img alt="Foto" src="http://shots.ikbis.com/image/35515/large/Hummer_H2_89_1280x1024.jpg" width="200" height="150" class="leftimg" />
  </div>

  <div class="text">
    Текст текст текст текст
  </div>


  <div class="array_Button">
    <a href="">
      <div class="myButton">Читать далее ...</div>
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в ваш css:

```
.array_blog {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
 }
.array_blog:before,
.array_blog:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.array_blog:after {
  clear: both;
}

.array_Button {
    float: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```